pkgdown website not showing up on github but shows up on my local drive without any issues
I'm building a package that automatically builds ensembles. The GitHub URL for the repository is:
https://www.github.com/InfiniteCuriosity/Ensembles
The package runs without any errors or warnings. When I go to build a website:
pkgdown::build_site()

the site is built without any errors. I can see it clearly on my local drive.

Some of the data on the website on my local drive is on my GitHub page, but a lot is not on the GitHub homepage, such as Browse source code, and Report a bug.
The permission appear to be correct:

The code that it seems I can't get to work is:
usethis::use_pkgdown_github_pages()

However, R tells me the URL for the website on Github is:
https://infinitecuriosity.github.io/Ensembles/
That page returns an error, and I can't find it on my repository.

How can the webpage be published on Github?
